# Overfull \hbox from multiple tabular environments on same line

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\parindent=0pt
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{E1}
      &
      \textbf{E2}
      &
      \textbf{E3}
      &
      \textbf{E4}
  \\\hline

            O
            O
      &
            O
            O
      &
            O
            X
      &
            O
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{V1}
      &
      \textbf{V2}
      &
      \textbf{V3}
      &
      \textbf{V4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            O
            O
      &
            O
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{S1}
      &
      \textbf{S2}
      &
      \textbf{S3}
      &
      \textbf{S4}
  \\\hline

            O
            X
      &
            O
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{A1}
      &
      \textbf{A2}
      &
      \textbf{A3}
      &
      \textbf{A4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{M1}
      &
      \textbf{M2}
      &
      \textbf{M3}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{G1}
      &
      \textbf{G2}
      &
      \textbf{G3}
      &
      \textbf{G4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}



\end{document}
```

[image: overflowMWE]

I'm writing a program that automatically generates the above LaTeX source based on gradebook data. In particular, I don't know how many tables the program will generate or how many columns each table will have (up to a maximum of 8). To conserve space, I wanted to generate these tables inline so that they would automatically break lines as needed. Obviously, that's not happening as intended. How can I get the line to break if the next table would overflow the horizontal line width, or is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: put `\raggedright` at the start

Comment: note that `\hspace{2em} \begin{tabular}` puts a word space as well as a 2em space between each table (don't know if that matters or not)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\allowbreak`  won't do anything if there is already space, as the line can break at a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tex is trying to justify the lines, but since the tables are big there are few stretchy word spaces on each line so it is bound to fail, If you set the blocks raggedright things go better

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}%\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{E1}
      &
      \textbf{E2}
      &
      \textbf{E3}
      &
      \textbf{E4}
  \\\hline

            O
            O
      &
            O
            O
      &
            O
            X
      &
            O
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{V1}
      &
      \textbf{V2}
      &
      \textbf{V3}
      &
      \textbf{V4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            O
            O
      &
            O
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{S1}
      &
      \textbf{S2}
      &
      \textbf{S3}
      &
      \textbf{S4}
  \\\hline

            O
            X
      &
            O
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{A1}
      &
      \textbf{A2}
      &
      \textbf{A3}
      &
      \textbf{A4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{M1}
      &
      \textbf{M2}
      &
      \textbf{M3}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{G1}
      &
      \textbf{G2}
      &
      \textbf{G3}
      &
      \textbf{G4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}% best not to have this last space\hspace{2em}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Both this and @steven-b-segletes solutions work well. I actually went with the justified solution, but this is probably the most correct answer since my original example was ragged.

Answer (score 3):

I replaced each occurrence of `\hspace{2em}` with `\hspace{2em}\hfill` (commenting out the very final `\hfill`.

This will provide justified margins, with a minimum of 2em gap between adjacent tabulars.  The tabulars will be evenly distributed across a given line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\parindent=0pt
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{E1}
      &
      \textbf{E2}
      &
      \textbf{E3}
      &
      \textbf{E4}
  \\\hline

            O
            O
      &
            O
            O
      &
            O
            X
      &
            O
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{V1}
      &
      \textbf{V2}
      &
      \textbf{V3}
      &
      \textbf{V4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            O
            O
      &
            O
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{S1}
      &
      \textbf{S2}
      &
      \textbf{S3}
      &
      \textbf{S4}
  \\\hline

            O
            X
      &
            O
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{A1}
      &
      \textbf{A2}
      &
      \textbf{A3}
      &
      \textbf{A4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{M1}
      &
      \textbf{M2}
      &
      \textbf{M3}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}\hline

      \textbf{G1}
      &
      \textbf{G2}
      &
      \textbf{G3}
      &
      \textbf{G4}
  \\\hline

            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
      &
            X
            X
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}\hspace{2em}%\hfill



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes if the OP wants it justified rather than ragged (although the allowbreak isn't needed)

Comment: You've been robbed, see the comment under my answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Story of my life.